# Brocade OSPFv3 Routes are not installed

Tags: ipv6, ospf, brocade

I am trying to deploy OSPFv3 across our network. However a few routers do not install the OSPFv3 route's to their routing tables. For example, this router is able to ping a certain host on the network.

```
#sh ipv6 ospf routes fd42:1337::9:2
   Destination                    Cost       E2Cost     Tag        Flags    Dis
IA fd42:1337::9:0/112             2          0          0          00000003 110
   Next_Hop_Router                Outgoing_Interface Adv_Router
   1   fe80::224:38ff:fe98:af00       ve 14              10.39.0.1

#sh ipv6 route fd42:1337::9:2
Type Codes - B:BGP C:Connected I:ISIS L:Local O:OSPF R:RIP S:Static
BGP  Codes - i:iBGP e:eBGP
ISIS Codes - L1:Level-1 L2:Level-2
OSPF Codes - i:Inter Area 1:External Type 1 2:External Type 2
STATIC Codes - d:DHCPv6
        Type IPv6 Prefix           Next Hop Router    Interface     Dis/Metric     Uptime src-vrf
1       O    fd42:1337::9:0/112    fe80::224:38ff:fe98:af00
                                                      ve 14         110/2          1d1h   -
#ping ipv6 fd42:1337::9:2
Sending 1, 16-byte ICMPv6 Echo to fd42:1337::9:2
timeout 5000 msec, Hop Limit 64
Type Control-c to abort
Reply from fd42:1337::9:2: bytes=16 time=1ms Hop Limit=63
Success rate is 100 percent (1/1), round-trip min/avg/max=1/1/1 ms.

Tracing the route to IPv6 node fd42:1337::9:2 from 1 to 30 hops
  1    26 ms   <1 ms   <1 ms fd42:1337::4:1
  2    99 ms   <1 ms   <1 ms fd42:1337::9:2
```

However, the router that is a neighbor of the above router (1 hop further away) is unable to reach this network, even though the network is in it's ospf database.

```
#sh ipv6 ospf routes fd42:1337::9:2
   Destination                    Cost       E2Cost     Tag        Flags    Dis
IA fd42:1337::9:0/112             3          0          0          00000002 110
   Next_Hop_Router                Outgoing_Interface Adv_Router
   1   fe80::768e:f8ff:fe29:9f00      ve 15              10.39.0.5

#sh ipv route fd42:1337::9:2
Can't find matching entry

Tracing the route to IPv6 node fd42:1337::9:2 from 1 to 30 hops

  1    *       *       *     ?
  2    *       *       *     ?
```

The above 2 routers have an ajecency on VE15 which is in the full state.

```
#sh ipv6 ospf neighbor

Total number of neighbors in all states: 2
Number of neighbors in state Full      : 2

RouterID        Pri State    DR              BDR             Interface     [State]
10.39.0.5         1 Full     10.39.0.5       10.13.13.223    ve 15         [BDR]
10.39.0.9         1 Full     10.39.0.9       10.13.13.223    ve 19         [BDR]
```

I have already tried clearing the OSPFv3 process, however no luck here. I have also enabled OSPFv3 debugging, the debug output contained the following info (filtered on the ipv6 address and router id):

```
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF: 10.39.0.5:1553(N) is the first hop
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF : 10.39.0.5:1553(N) nexthop :: ifindex 1553
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF: Examining Vertex: 10.39.0.5:1553(N)
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF: new node added to candidate list: 10.39.0.5:1553(N)
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF: installing vertex 10.39.0.5:1553(N)
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: ROUTE: Creating route: 10.39.0.5:1553(N)
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF : 10.39.0.5:0 nexthop fe80::768e:f8ff:fe29:9f00 ifindex 1553
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF: Examining Vertex: 10.39.0.5:0
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF: new node added to candidate list: 10.39.0.5:0
Aug 23 15:37:23.427 OSPFv3: SPF: Ignore link description to myself
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: SPF: installing vertex 10.39.0.5:0
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: ROUTE: Creating route: 10.39.0.5:0
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: SPF: 10.39.0.5:1552(N) inherits 10.39.0.5:0's nexthop_list
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: SPF: Examining Vertex: 10.39.0.5:1552(N)
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: SPF: new node added to candidate list: 10.39.0.5:1552(N)
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: SPF: 10.39.0.5:1553(N) inherits 10.39.0.5:0's nexthop_list
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: SPF: Examining Vertex: 10.39.0.5:1553(N)
Aug 23 15:37:23.428 OSPFv3: SPF: already in SPF tree: 10.39.0.5:1553(N)

..snip..

Aug 23 15:37:23.465 OSPFv3: INTRA AREA ROUTE: Can't find Prefix LSA for Vertex Type 0 id 0.0.0.0 AdvRouter 10.39.0.5

..snip..

Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: INTRA AREA ROUTE: found Prefix LSA type : IntraPrefix : for Vertex Type 1 Id 0.0.6.16 Advrouter 10.39.0.5
Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: INTRA AREA ROUTE: Intra Area route install fd42:1337::4:0/112 cost 2, area 0.0.0.0
Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: ROUTE: Creating route: fd42:1337::4:0/112
Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: INTRA AREA ROUTE: found Prefix LSA type : IntraPrefix : for Vertex Type 1 Id 0.0.6.17 Advrouter 10.39.0.5
Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: INTRA AREA ROUTE: Intra Area route install fd42:1337::5:0/112 cost 1, area 0.0.0.0
Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: ROUTE: Creating route: fd42:1337::5:0/112

..snip..

Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: INTRA AREA ROUTE: found Prefix LSA type : IntraPrefix : for Vertex Type 1 Id 0.0.6.20 Advrouter 10.39.0.1
Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: INTRA AREA ROUTE: Intra Area route install fd42:1337::9:0/112 cost 3, area 0.0.0.0
Aug 23 15:37:23.466 OSPFv3: ROUTE: Creating route: fd42:1337::9:0/112

..snip..

Aug 23 15:37:23.474 OSPFv3: Validating route fd42:1337::9:0/112, nexthop cnt 1, route_info->flag 0x00000002
```

It seems the 2 routers are not properly neighboring, could anyone point me in the right direction as to fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be old routes from recent changes, try clearing the routing table:

`clear ipv6 ospf all`